# RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

List the ruby versions

```
console:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Try to use a specific version of ruby

```
console:~$ rvm use 2.0.0

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What terminal do you use? Setting the login shell differs per terminal application. Alternatively you could `source $HOME/.profile` or `source $HOME/.bash_profile` where rvm has probably defined its init line.

Comment: You need to run your console as a login shell. What system do you have?

Comment: Terminal Gnome the Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Comment: You could just have typed /bin/bash --login from your terminal. and then give rvm use 2.0.0..

Comment: In case you are wondering what the difference between a login vs non-login shell: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Comment: Just restart the terminal

Comment: @stephenbez thanks for the link though :)

Comment: @BroiSatse, why does RVM require a login shell?. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277999/why-does-rvm-use-command-require-suggest-a-login-shell

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Your console is not running as a login shell and hence have no access to rvm function. If you are running Ubuntu, you can:

1. Open console
2. Select Edit -> Profile Preferences
3. Select tab: Title and Command
4. Check box 'Run command as a login shell'
5. Restart terminal

Comment: I did that but did not work. The problem persists . How to remove rvm completely?

Comment: Of course you will need the following in your ~/.profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Comment: I think this could be explained more ― "and hence have no access to rvm function"

Comment: It worked. Bu can you tell the difference between those two?

Comment: What works for me on OSX is `/bin/bash --login; source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; rvm use 2.4.0`

Comment: for centos 7.1 or any centos in ~/.bashrc file, past:   source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Comment: if your are using `zsh-terminal` add the rvm scripts path in **~/.zshrc** instead of *~/.bashrc*: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Answer (score 155):

Type `bash --login` from your terminal. And then give `rvm use 2.0.0`

Comment: @AdityaPednekar So, sometimes reading the error/console message actually helps, 

`RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use /bin/bash --login as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.` specifies the details.

Comment: Yeah, It helps realize how unreasonably complex it is to use `rvm` compared to `nvm`

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and it saved lot of time.

Answer (score 93):

It seems like your rvm does not load ".bash_profile" properly. I have done to fix it in MAC OS X or Ubuntu 14.04 by opening terminal and write:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: In my case I was on new m1 macos with zsh as default shell and had to instead add that line to `.zprofile`

Answer (score 59):

My env is OSX Yosemite. Had the same issue .... solved by adding the following

1) edit and add the following line to ***.bash_profile*** file.

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

2) Restart terminal and try RVM command again

Comment: You can add this to ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc (if your are using zsh) too.

Comment: If you don't want or cannot restart the terminal, you can run `source ~/.bash_profile` after editing it.

Answer (score 48):

If you don't want that every time you open a terminal, do the suggestion above again, just add

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

at the end of `~/.bashrc`

Comment: This one helped.

Comment: .. and needs a restart ?

Comment: @gordie Nope, simply execute `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 27):

The error is due to rvm is not running as in login shell. Hence try the below command:

```
/bin/bash --login
```

You will able run rvm commands instantly as login shell in terminal.

Answer (score 16):

Same principle as other answers, just thought it was quicker than re-opening terminals :)

```
bash -l -c "rvm use 2.0.0"
```

Comment: Someone should come up with a better answer than all of these.  This is the only item in all the answers to this question that works for me but this is not something I want to do all the time.  Im on Mac OSX Sierra

Answer (score 12):

You need to add `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to `~/.your_shellrc file`. From now when you load a shell, rvm will be loaded.

For example:

if you are using zsh shell, need to add in `~/.zshrc` file

if you are using bash shell, need to add in `~/.bashrc` file

And then open a new tab to see the effect.

Answer (score 12):

I think this more generic solution

```
echo 'source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This should really be the answer.

Answer (score 9):

For me in Ubuntu(18.08), I have added below line in .bashrc and it works.

```
 source /home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Please add this line.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on MacOS! As a suggestion, I think it's better to use `~` to refer to user's home path: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` :-)

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 9):

Following work for me in ubuntu 19.1

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: This worked for me using WSL2 Ubuntu. Thanks 

Comment: @Sagar Jethi, you made my day.

Answer (score 3):

From a new Ubuntu 16.04 Installation

1) Terminal => Edit => Profile Preferences

2) Command Tab => Check Run command as a login shell

3) Close, and reopen terminal

```
rvm --default use 2.2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

If RVM was installed with dedicated ubuntu RVM installer https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm the path to RVM scripts will be different `/usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm`. So to add it to your `.bashrc` run the following command:

```
echo 'source "/usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW- I just ran across this as well, it was in the context of a cancelled selenium run. Perhaps there was a sub-shell being instantiated and left in place. Closing that terminal window and opening a new one was all I needed to do. (macOS Sierra)

Answer (score 0):

```
     Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
     You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
     To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.6.5
     To ignore this error add "rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1" to your "~/.rvmrc" file.
```