# ruby version on remote server is not changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, rvm, ubuntu-14.04, rvm-capistrano

This is about configuring remote Ubuntu server through SSH utility for hosting Ruby on Rails application. From beginning I've installed all the environments using **'root'** user, after installing tools I created other user - '**deploy**' for Capistrano deployments. Now, when I connect to remote server with '**deploy**' user account, for some reason it is showing `'$ ruby -v' - 1.9.3`, but I have 2.3.0 installed. when I run '$ rvm list' - it shows correct version of the ruby installed and current, same as default set to 2.3.0. When I run `'$ bash --login'`, than `'$ ruby -v'` and `'$ rvm list`' are both showing the right version of the Ruby, so there is another issue. I think it's because I installed ruby and RVM with **'root'** user, but now trying to make deployment with **'deploy'** user.

Also, during deployment of the ruby application, it shows error that RAKE gem is not installed. I know for sure that RAKE and other Gems are installed.

When logged in with deploy user credentials, the `'ruby -v'` shows 1.9.3, so I tried to call `'rvm use 2.3.0 --default'` but error is shown:

> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not
>   work.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've guessed, `rvm` needs to be installed for the `deploy` user. It's a per-user setting.

Edit: Problem already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963018/rvm-is-not-a-function-selecting-rubies-with-rvm-use-will-not-work)

Comment: when I try to install rvm for that user, it is saying that rvm is already there:
Upgrading the RVM installation in /home/deploy/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /home/deploy/.mkshrc /home/deploy/.profile /home/deploy/.bashrc /home/deploy/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /home/deploy/.profile /home/deploy/.bash_profile /home/deploy/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /home/deploy/.rvm/ is complete.
deploy@xxx:~$ rvm use 2.3.0 --default
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

Comment: I believe your problem has already been solved then :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963018/rvm-is-not-a-function-selecting-rubies-with-rvm-use-will-not-work